# Isotope Elements overlapping

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, jquery-isotope

I'm having difficulty with the isotope (with masonry module). Or the module found at https://www.drupal.org/project/views_isotope. I've applied this module and copied their example almost exactly. Yet my view doesn't work. It almost works, I get the grid and the filter. The filter works, and the images rearrange, but when I refresh the page and the filter resets to all, the isotope elements are scrambled or overlapping.

[picture of scrambled isotope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKVpX.png)

I should say that, I do not get this overlapping issue when I refresh the example view that came with the module.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where's your code? Posting just an image is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You should use imagesLoaded JQuery plugin with Isotope. Info can be found [here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/faq.html). You should always use imagesLoaded plugin when using images inside grid items. Otherwise images can be still loading when elements are arranged.